# Automated tree-farm in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen a few videoes where people create near (or completely) automated tree farms in Minecraft, so I thought I'd give it a go.

I'm playing 1.7.3 beta SMP though, no mods (at least none that alter game behavior.)

One of the things I saw one guy had made was something that automated planting a tree, and then automated applying a bonemeal, before finally he automated flooding the area with water to destroy the tree and gather the trunk items.

One thing at a time.

My question is thus this:

- Is it possible to automate the "plant a sapling" part?

I tried the following:

1. I set out a dispenser, pointed towards a block of dirt, but at the same level as the dirt-block. In other words, the "hole" in the dispenser was not visible, and led directly into the dirt-block
2. I set out the dispenser, pointing towards the dirt-block, but one level above the dirt-block

In both cases, when powered, a sapling item was dropped on top of the dirt-block. I assume that when the dispenser "submerged" at the same level as the dirt-block dispensed a sapling, it floated to the top due to the same rules that makes item float to the top of newly placed blocks.

So, is this part even possible without a mod?

Comment: It's the same with my wheat harvesting machine. The wheat is automatically harvested and transported and the drains for the water are hidden until the automated harvesting starts. The only thing I got to do myself is planting the seeds again. :/

Comment: How did water destroy the tree? I'd love to see the video of this!

Comment: @RonanForman he was talking about an automated wheat farm not for trees.

Comment: Not to whoever finds this question in the future: It is an extremely old question and all answers are very outdated. It is possible to create an AFK wood farm, but you need to trap a wither or somehow transport creepers to whatever location you transport the logs to and cause them to explode. It's extremely difficult, therefore most people rely on bugusing to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know it is impossible without using a mod, but maybe in some future release... I hope so.

Comment: Oh, well, will have to "make do" with just a boatload of trees then.

Answer (score -1):

LivingForest is a bukkit mod that I use and I'm quite happy with it. It does tree planting, fast growth, and a favorite of mine for landscaping is it allows you to tweak the spawn rate of "big" trees.