# How can I farm Phantoms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing a LOT of Minecraft with this new update, and I pretty much never sleep because of the addition of phantoms. As many people know, they swoop down and attack players that haven't slept for 3 nights. I like killing them for their membrane, as it is very useful so I'd like to set up some sort of mechanism to farm them.

All the ideas I can find on Google don't seem to good, I'm hoping that someone had invented one that was a bit unique and maybe if there was a better way instead of just beating them with a sword.

How can I construct a Phantom farm?

Comment: @closers: This question is perfectly on-topic for the site, as [we](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190274/how-can-i-make-a-fairly-efficient-chicken-farm) have [several](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202584/how-can-i-farm-guardians) other [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124893/how-can-i-make-a-zombie-pigman-farm) like [it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29057/automated-tree-farm-in-minecraft?rq=1). If you disagree please make a meta or leave comment explaining how this is drastically different than the questions linked above. Thanks.

Comment: If you've already come across several farms online that don't work for you for some reason I'd encourage you to edit your question to include some more details about your specific criteria, as it'll help folks tailor an answer for you. On the other hand, if you've come across a farm or have invented one yourself that works really well then feel free to answer your own question, so others can benefit from your solution too! Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ilmango is a very good youtuber that helps explain the mechanics, from chunk loading behaviours, tick mechanics, and spawning mechanics. He has posted a video about how phantom spawning works, and a demonstration about how farming them works

Additionally, it was Mr. Tiger that came up with the original farm that uses these mechanics, to drown the phantoms. Here is the tutorial for the farm:

Answer (score -2):

This thread is outdated and those videos no longer are accurate.
This video explains it very well and makes it very easy to farm them.
However it is currently only for Bedrock edition but will eventually work on Java come the new update.

Comment: Welcome to Arcade. it's encourged that you summarize/explain the video you have linked to in the event it was taken down